# Make and run from vim

Tags: makeprg

I just got into `:make` and I love the ability to browse the errors.

However, in my usual workflow, I am interested in running make and then running some executable. So my to-go option so far was to run something along the lines of `:!pushd build && make && ./bin/exec`. As I said, I love the way I can browse the compile issues I get with `:make`, but can I somehow combine this with running the executable?

Editing the makefile to include this as a target is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since editing your makefile is not an option then may need to edit your `'makeprg'` setting to accommodate your build process

```
:setlocal makeprg build\ &&\ make\ &&\ ./bin/exec
```

See `'makeprg'` for more details

Answer (score 3):

As Peter mentioned, you can execute your program and send its outputs to the quickfix window.

If you want to execute it elsewhere (which could be necessary if you run an interactive program, or if your wish to execute it in a terminal), then a little bit of programming is required. See this *almost-duplicate* Q/A for a solution: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34584/626